# Why can't we specialize concepts?

Tags: c++, c++20, template-specialization, c++-concepts

The syntax that works for classes does not work for concepts:

```
template <class Type>
concept C = requires(Type t) {
    // ...
};


template <class Type>
concept C<Type*> = requires(Type t) {
    // ...
};
```

MSVC says for the line of the "specialization": `error C7606: 'C': concept cannot be explicitly instantiated, explicitly specialized or partially specialized`.

Why cannot concepts be specialized? Is there a theoretical reason?

Comment: This seems like it would make it hard on the user of the concept, who's relying on this for how they can use the type they have. Now they also have to specialize or similar in order to have usage of the type follow the concept. Do you have a particular motivating example in mind?

Comment: Motivating example (this is the usage): `IsCallableWithSignature<MyType, void(int, bool)>`. A straightforward way to implement this would be to specialize the concept. Workaround with a class: [link](https://godbolt.org/z/KG5jdbG3z).

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Because it would ruin constraint normalization and subsumption rules.

As it stands now, every `concept` has exactly and only one definition. As such, the relationships between concepts are known and *fixed*. Consider the following:

```
template<typename T>
concept A = atomic_constraint_a<T>;

template<typename T>
concept B = atomic_constraint_a<T> && atomic_constraint_b<T>;
```

By C++20's current rules, `B` subsumes `A`. This is because, after constraint normalization, `B` includes all of the atomic constraints of `A`.

If we allow specialization of concepts, then the relationship between `B` and `A` now depends on the *arguments* supplied to those concepts. `B<T>` might subsume `A<T>` for some `T`s but not other `T`s.

But that's not how we *use* concepts. If I'm trying to write a template that is "more constrained" than another template, the only way to do that is to use a known, well-defined set of concepts. And those definitions *cannot* depend on the parameters to those concepts.

The compiler ought to be able to compute whether one constrained template is more constrained than another *without* having any template arguments *at all*. This is important, as having one template be "more constrained" than another is a key feature of using concepts and constraints.

Ironically, allowing specialization for concepts would break (constrained) specialization for *other templates*. Or at the very least, it'd make it really hard to implement.

Comment: I believe you can cheat by forwarding a concept to a template which is specialized; which, in effect, makes an atomic constraint.  I could see the utility in having "special atomic" constraints that can be specialized (or pattern matched in other ways), or at least a better syntax than the trait class specialization stuff we have.  Syntactic sugar, but that matters.

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont: But by turning it into an atomic constraint black box, you lose any meaning for the concept itself. If you did this to, for example, `random_access_iterator`, it would no longer subsume `bidirectional_iterator`. We should have syntactic sugar for *good* ideas, not for things you shouldn't do.

Comment: Suppose, that the current subsumtion rules are this: `B` subsumes `A` iff _X_. I would propose enabling specialization and modifying the rule to this: `B` subsumes `A` iff neither of them has a specialization and _X_. Might work?

Comment: @Dr.Gut: What exactly would be the point of that? If you can't guarantee subsumption, then you can't rely on it. I shouldn't be able to write a template that expects a subsumption relationship to exist, and then have you come along and break that with a specialization. Just make it a `constexpr inline static bool` variable where subsumption doesn't exist and specialization does.

Comment: @NicolBolas: This made me think. It was a bad idea. Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

In addition to the great answer from Nicol Bolas:

Concepts are a bit special, because they don't behave like other templated things:

[13.7.9 Concept definitions](https://eel.is/c++draft/temp.concept#5)

> <sup>(5)</sup> A concept is not instantiated ([[temp.spec]](https://eel.is/c++draft/temp.spec)).
> [*Note [1](https://eel.is/c++draft/temp.concept#note-1)*: A concept-id ([[temp.names]](https://eel.is/c++draft/temp.names)) is evaluated as an expression. A concept cannot be explicitly instantiated ([[temp.explicit]](https://eel.is/c++draft/temp.explicit)), explicitly specialized ([[temp.expl.spec]](https://eel.is/c++draft/temp.expl.spec)), or partially specialized ([[temp.spec.partial]](https://eel.is/c++draft/temp.spec.partial)). — *end note*]

Due to concepts not being able to be instantiated they also can't be specialized.

I'm not sure on why the standard decided to not make them specializable, given that it's easy to emulate specializations.

---

While you can't specialize concepts directly, there are quite a few ways you can work around the problem.

You can use any type of constant expression in a concept - so you could use a templated variable (which can be specialized) and just wrap it up into a concept - the standard does this for quite a few of its own concepts as well, e.g. `std::is_intergral`:

```cpp
template<class T> struct is_integral;

// is_integral is specialized for integral types to have value == true
// and all others are value == false

template<class T>
inline constexpr bool is_integral_v = is_­integral<T>::value;

template<class T>
concept integral = is_­integral_­v<T>;
```

So you could easily write a concept that has specializations like this: [godbolt example](https://godbolt.org/z/EWbvhsGKG)

```cpp
struct Foo{};
struct Bar{};

template<class T>
constexpr inline bool is_addable_v = requires(T t) {
    { t + t } -> std::same_as<T>;
};

// Specializations (could also use other requires clauses here)
template<>
constexpr inline bool is_addable_v<Foo> = true;

template<class T>
constexpr inline bool is_addable_v<T&&> = true;

template<class T>
concept is_addable = is_addable_v<T>; 

int main() {
    static_assert(is_addable<int>);
    static_assert(is_addable<Foo>);
    static_assert(!is_addable<Bar>);
    static_assert(is_addable<Bar&&>);
}
```

Or by using a class:

```cpp
template<class T>
struct is_addable_v : std::true_type {};

template<>
struct is_addable_v<struct FooBar> : std::false_type {};

template<class T>
concept is_addable = is_addable_v<T>::value;
```

Or even a constexpr lambda: [godbolt example](https://godbolt.org/z/43T6j41b7)

```cpp
// pointers must add to int
// everything else must add to double
template<class T>
concept is_special_addable = ([](){
    if constexpr(std::is_pointer_v<T>)
        return requires(std::remove_pointer_t<T> t) {
            { t + t } -> std::same_as<int>;
        };
    else
        return requires(T t) {
            { t + t } -> std::same_as<double>;
        };
})(); 

int main() {
    static_assert(is_special_addable<double>);
    static_assert(is_special_addable<int*>);
    static_assert(!is_special_addable<double*>);
    static_assert(!is_special_addable<int>);
}
```

So while concepts can't be specialized on their own, it's easy to achieve the same effect with existing language features.

Answer (score 5):

Specialization in this sort of situation opens up a bag of worms.  We opened this bag up once with template specialization.  Template specialization is a major part of what makes the template language in general Turing complete.  Yes, you can program in templates.  You shouldn't, but you can.  Boost has a library called Boost.MPL that's chock full of clever things, like an "unordered map" that operates at compile time, rather than run time.

So we would have to restrict it carefully.  Simple cases may work, but complex cases would have to be forbidden.  Certainly anything that is remotely capable of creating a recursive constraint would have to be watched carefully.  Indeed, consider a concept:

```
template <typename T>
concept hailstone = false;

template <int i>
concept hailstone<std::integral_constant<int, i> =
    hailstone<2 * i> || (i % 2 == 1 && hailstone<3*i - 1>);

template <>
concept hailstone<std::integral_constant<int, 0> = true;
```

so, is `std::integral_constant<int, 27>` a hailstone?  It could take a while.  My chosen example is based on hailstone numbers from the [Collatz Conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collatz_conjecture).  Determining whether any given number is a hailstone or not is painfully difficult (even though, as best as we can tell, *every* number is a hailstone number).

Now replace integral_constant with a clever structure which can do arbitrary precision.  Now we're in trouble!

Now we can carefully slice off elements of this problem and mark them as doable.  The spec community is not in that business.  The Concepts we know in C++20 has been nicknamed concepts-lite because it's actually a drastically simplified version of a concepts library that never made it into C++11.  That library effectively implemented a [Description Logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Description_logic), a class of logic that is known to be decidable.  This was important because the computer had to run through all of the necessary calculations, and we didn't want them to take an infinite amount of time.  Concepts is derived from this, so it follows the same rules.  And, if you look in Description Logics, the way you prove many statements involves first enumerating the list of all *named* concepts.  Once you had enumerated that, it was trivial to show that you could resolve any concept requirement in finite time.

As Nicol Bolas points out in his answer, the purpose of concepts was not to be some clever Turing complete system.  It was to provide better error messages.  Thus, while one might be able to cleverly slide in *some* specialization within carefully selected paths, there's no incentive to.