# Why do we need the concept keyword in C++20?

Tags: c++, c++20, language-design, c++-concepts

Concepts are great, don't get me wrong, but why do we need another keyword for this?

Consider the following example:

```cpp
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T>
concept UnsignedConst = std::is_integral_v<T> && std::is_const_v<T>;

template <UnsignedConst T>
void foo(T bar);
```

We could as well be using the following -- in my opinion more straight-forward -- syntax:

```cpp
/* ... */
template <typename T>
constexpr bool UnsignedConst = std::is_integral_v<T> && std::is_const_v<T>;
/* ... */
```

Under the hood, concepts are nothing more than compile-time boolean constants contingent on template parameters (**EDIT:** NO! See accepted answer). Even `requires`-clauses could be utilized with variable templates as they are just expressions which evaluate to boolean values at compile-time.

Comment: What you propse already exists. Its a variable template, not a concept

Comment: *"concepts are nothing more than compile-time boolean constants"*. There are **subsumption rules** which works on concepts (and not on underlying conditions).

Comment: didnt read it yet, but I'd expect some good motivation to be found here: https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2005/n1886.pdf

Comment: Aside from the subsumption rules, which offer some valuable clarity to code, your example doesn't demonstrate how `UnsignedConst auto` would work as a type.  It can mostly be synthesized in C++17, but it's pretty ugly and verbose and people have trouble reading it.

Comment: I know about variable templates, I just thought concepts were unneccessary because of their existence

Comment: then your question is not phrased very well, it talks only about the syntax and about introduction of a keyword. Variable templates vs concepts on the other hand is about 2 language features

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> Under the hood, concepts are nothing more than compile-time boolean constants contingent on template parameters.

This is untrue.

A `concept` has special properties that mere `constexpr bool`s do not. In particular, a `concept` cannot be specialized. This inability to be specialized [makes concept subsumption rules *possible*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70828903/734069). It allows the standard to lay down rules for what counts as a "more specialized" version of a template.

Given the following:

```
template<typename T>
concept A = atomic_constraint_a<T>;

template<typename T>
concept B = atomic_constraint_a<T> && atomic_constraint_b<T>;
```

it is clear within the rules of C++ concepts that `A` is subsumed by `B`. This means that any type `T` which fulfills `B` *necessarily* fulfills `A`. Therefore, if you have two templates, one constrained on `A` and one on `B`, if you pass a type that fulfills `B`, that is the one which will be chosen even if there is a version for `A`.

Specialization would *ruin* this, because someone could come along and specialize `B` for a type `U` in such a way that `A<U>` does not subsume `B<U>`.

So... what should happen then? What happens when someone tries to provide `U` to the above template with competing constraints? The primary constraints say that there is a subsumption relationship, but the specialized one does not.

More importantly, can I even write two concepts with a subsumption relationship and ensure that this will be maintained? That is, in a world with specialization, can I rely on subsumption in my template interfaces?

No, the only way to make subsumption possible is to forbid specialization. But variable templates can be specialized. So now you need a new construct that says "I'm kinda like that thing but you can't specialize me". We could make everyone type `template<typename T> [[nonspecialized]] inline constexpr bool concept_name = X` in order to get subsumption (and other things concepts provide).

Or we could just say `template<typename T> concept concept_name = x` and eliminate a bunch of syntactic noise.

Also, `concept`s cannot be members of classes. That's important too, as this means you can't have a *de facto* specialization of a concept by specializing the class *around* the concept.

Furthermore, by making a `concept` a special syntactic construct, introduced by its own grammatical token, it allows the language to more easily be able to use `concept`s in novel places. For example, `std::integral auto var_name = func();`. The compiler can see that `std::integral` is an identifier that represents a concept. If it saw a `constexpr bool` variable, you *might* intend to use it as a concept. Or you might have intended to use it in some other way. By making concepts a distinct kind of thing, we eliminate any ambiguity.

This is what allows us to use type-concepts in various ways within the grammar, a thing that would be... difficult without specialized syntax. Maybe you could have an attribute or something applied to `constexpr inline bool`, but again... why all the keywords when you just mean `concept`?